# Como vou a poder otimizar o algoritmo para encontrar a maior subsequência comum (MSC) entre duas strings?

Tags: java, algoritmo

Um algoritmo utilizado para encontrar com eficiência o MSC entre duas strings:

1. Defina duas strings, string1 e string2, com comprimentos m e n, respectivamente.
2. Crie uma matriz 2D, dp, com dimensões (m+1) x (n+1). Inicialize todos os elementos de dp com 0.
3. Itere sobre os caracteres de string1 da esquerda para a direita (i) e string2 de cima para baixo (j).
4. Se string1[i] for igual a string2[j], incremente dp[i+1][j+1] em 1. Isso significa que os caracteres atuais correspondem e o comprimento do MSC que termina neste ponto é um a mais que o MSC terminando nos caracteres anteriores.
5. Se string1[i] não for igual a string2[j], pegue o valor máximo entre dp[i][j+1] e dp[i+1][j] e armazene-o em dp[i+1][j +1]. Isso significa que os caracteres atuais não correspondem, portanto, o comprimento do MSC que termina neste ponto é o máximo do MSC que termina nos caracteres anteriores em string1 ou string2.
   6.Após iterar todos os caracteres, o valor de dp[m][n] será o comprimento do LCS entre string1 e string2.
6. Para recuperar o LCS real, comece em dp[m][n] e volte pela matriz dp. Se string1[i-1] for igual a string2[j-1], adicione o caractere ao LCS e mova diagonalmente para dp[i-1][j-1]. Caso contrário, mova para a esquerda se dp[i][j-1] for maior que dp[i-1][j] ou mova para cima se dp[i-1][j] for maior.
7. Repita a etapa 7 até chegar ao canto superior esquerdo da matriz dp.

Seguindo este algoritmo, a maior subsequência comum entre duas strings pode ser encontrada na programação.

Um exemplo de código Java:

```
public static String repeatCharacter(char ch, int length) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        sb.append(ch);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
char ch = 'X';

System.out.println("Enter size of first string");
int m = myObj.next();
String string1 = repeatCharacter(ch, m);
System.out.println("Enter size of first string");
int m = myObj.next()
String string2 = repeatCharacter(ch, n);
String lcs = "";

System.out.println("Enter first string");
string1 = myObj.nextLine(); 
System.out.println("Enter second string");
string1 = myObj.nextLine(); 
int dp[m+1][n+1];
int i, j;

for (i = 0; i < m + 1; i++) {
     for (j = 0; j < n + 1; j++) {
          dp[i][j] = 0;
     }
}

for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
     for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
          if (string1[i] = string2[j])
              dp[i+1][j+1]++;
          else
              dp[i+1][j+1] = Math.max(dp[i][j+1], dp[i+1][j]);
     }
}

i = m, j = n;
while (i > -1 && j > -1) {
    if (string1[i-1] = string2[j-1]) {
        lcs = lcs + string1[i-1];
        i--;
        j--;
    }
    else if (dp[i][j-1] > dp[i-1][j])
        i--;
    else
        j--;
}
```

No entanto, a utilização de loops for aninhados vai a poder tomar O(m n) tanto no tempo quanto no espaço.

Como vou a poder otimizar a complexidade do tempo e a complexidade do espaço deste algoritmo?

<sub>Tradução de [inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77808341/how-can-i-optimize-the-algorithm-to-find-the-longest-common-subsequence-lcs-be) e [espanhol](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/611437/c%c3%b3mo-voy-a-poder-optimizar-el-algoritmo-para-encontrar-la-subsecuencia-com%c3%ban-m%c3%a1)</sub>

Comment: Estou indo a buscar outro algoritmo ainda melhor.

Comment: Pedir “um algoritmo melhor” e colocar a afirmação parece uma tarefa acadêmica e sem esforço (código de sua parte), as chances de receber uma resposta são baixas. Por outro lado, quais são os seus critérios? melhor em que sentido? Do jeito que a questão está, não se surpreenda se eles derem uma negativa e/ou fecharem (em todos os 3 lugares você tem uma negativa). Para evitar isso, faça a implementação em alguma linguagem de programação, coloque os cases, as métricas que você tem, os erros que existem, as entradas e saídas que você espera, tendo isso, é provável que alguém te dê uma mão.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Ao inves de usares uma matriz bidimensional dp[m+1][n+1], usa uma matriz unidimensional dp[n+1].
2. No loop de iteração sobre os carateres das strings, em vez de usares dois loops aninhados, use apenas um loop.
3. Mantem uma variável temporária prev para armazenar o valor dp[i-1][j-1] antes de ser atualizado no loop.

````
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static String repeatCharacter(char ch, int length) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            sb.append(ch);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
        char ch = 'X';

        System.out.println("Enter size of first string");
        int m = myObj.nextInt();
        String string1 = repeatCharacter(ch, m);
        System.out.println("Enter size of second string");
        int n = myObj.nextInt();
        String string2 = repeatCharacter(ch, n);
        String lcs = "";

        System.out.println("Enter first string");
        string1 = myObj.next();
        System.out.println("Enter second string");
        string2 = myObj.next();

        int[] dp = new int[n + 1];
        int prev;

        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            prev = 0; // Inicialize prev para a diagonal superior esquerda dp[i-1][j-1]
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                int temp = dp[j + 1]; // Mantenha o valor dp[i-1][j] antes de ser atualizado
                if (string1.charAt(i) == string2.charAt(j))
                    dp[j + 1] = prev + 1;
                else
                    dp[j + 1] = Math.max(dp[j], dp[j + 1]);
                prev = temp; // Atualize prev para o próximo cálculo
            }
        }

        int i = m, j = n;
        while (i > 0 && j > 0) {
            if (string1.charAt(i - 1) == string2.charAt(j - 1)) {
                lcs = string1.charAt(i - 1) + lcs;
                i--;
                j--;
            } else if (dp[j] > dp[j - 1])
                i--;
            else
                j--;
        }

        System.out.println("LCS: " + lcs);
    }
}

    ```
````

Comment: Adicione mais detalhes à sua resposta. Sua resposta está recebendo votos negativos por falta de detalhes.